# Replacing a string with the regular expression ".*" returns the replacement twice

Tags: java, regex

Given this code :

```
String replaced = "A".replaceAll(".*", "HI");
```

Why does `replaced` contain the string `HIHI` instead of `HI` as I would have guessed? It seems that it has something to do with the beginning of a line since using the pattern `^.*` yields `HI`, but I don't get the reason for this.

Comment: You can use `.+` to prevent the empty string (`""`) to be matched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I *think* this is because `.*` first matches the entire string, and then matches the empty string at the end of string. Of course, `^.*` won't match the empty string at the end of "A", so you end up with only one "HI".

Answer (score 5):

Look at the replaceAll javadoc: Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.
This matches two substrings: "" and "A".
You can see this by testing

```
String replaced = "".replaceAll( ".*", "HI" );
```

Which results in a single "HI" being being printed

Comment: In "A" there are two positions (between the letters so to say): 0 and 1. At 0 "A" matches, at 1 "" matches.

Comment: @JoopEggen Anyway it's counter-intuitive. If `.*` is greedy it should "eat" entire string **including** the empty string at the end and return a match once.

Comment: two empty strings `"A".replaceAll("", "HI")==HIAHI`

Comment: @AdamDyga "greedy" (matching longest possible string) at position 0, but at position 1 it starts matching again.

Answer (score 0):

The find method of the Matcher class finds "A" and an empty String after the "A", so there are 2 replacements.

Answer (score 0):

The `replaceAll` method takes regex and replacement parameter as like ([read more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)) :-

```
public String replaceAll(String regex,
                         String replacement)
```

In this example `.*` represents the regular expression.

`.` indicates Any character (may or may not match line terminators)

`*` indicates  zero or more times ([Read More regexp](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum))

The output  of your given code is right . The regex is matches with `*`  means zero or more times . And it affects the result.

```
String replaced = "A".replaceAll(".*", "HI");
```

Output :- HIHI

Hope it will help you.